# How do I track a request on a page?

Tags: javascript

There is a page hosting a video on a third-party unpopular video host. There is no access to edit the page, it is a third-party CRM-system. I can only add some code to the head or body.

When the video viewer ends, the browser sends a POST request inside the system where the video lies, which conveys the fact that the particular video has been viewed.

Is there any way to track this request being sent in the background in order to do the action I want (e.g. send a notification to my manager)?

Comment: I don't think there is any such kind of an event in JavaScript. Maybe you could try using a breakpoint, but I don't think that would be suitable for you, given that you want to tap into the POST request's dispatch programmatically.

Comment: It _might_ be possible. See if you can figure out what technology is used to send the POST request. It's probably either XmlHttpRequest or fetch. Then mock that and add your own instrumentation. See if it's picked up by the original code. This can work in theory but it's super janky.

Comment: Yes, monkeypatching one of the request methods is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I don't want to tap into the POST request's... I need to know that a request has been sent. What it transmits is not important. And if the request has been sent, print an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can track the POST request if its successful Submited, return or run your code

Comment: But how?) I know which domain the browser sends the request to. How can I use JS to catch this trigger and perform the action I want (e.g. display an alert)?

Comment: if you know URL post you can use Ajax